# Prevent a method from being called if it is incorrect using __getattr__

Tags: python

I am trying to prevent an instance from throwing an exception if a method that does not exist for the instance is called. I have tried the following:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        print "Warning - method {0} does not exist for this instance".format(name)

o = myClass()
var = o.someNonExistantFunction()
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

The two things I want to make sure of doing is:

1. Return `None` as my code can deal with variables being set to `None`
2. Perform a function (printing a warning message)

What is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return a function that does nothing?

Couple of things:  first you might want to use `__getattr__` rather than `__getattribute__`.
`__getattr__` gets called when the runtime doesn't find anything by that name in the hierarchy, `__getattribute__` gets called every time.

```
class Test(object):
    def __getattr__(self,key):
        def placeholder(*args, **kwargs):
            print "Warning - method '%s' does not exist for this instance"%key
        return placeholder
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Just added the `*args, **kwargs` arguments for placeholder() to ensure that it can also deal with non-existent methods with arguments (which won't appear till it is peer-reviewed)

Answer (score 3):

Your `__getattr__` is the same as:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    print "Warning ..."
    return None
```

So, when you do `var = o.someNonExistantFunction()`, this is logically the same as:

```
var = o.someNonExistantFunction # == o.__getattr__('someNonExistantFunction') == None
var() # same as (None)()
```

Which is why you're getting the NoneType not callable error. Obtuse definitely has the rest of the answer, which is to return a callable function. However, you might think about other structural issues, and if it's truly a good idea to have a catchall function generator.

Comment: I'm guessing a Ruby background where method_missing? kludges are pretty common.

Comment: Hence the warning message letting me know to fix it some time in the future =)

Comment: whenever I start working with python plumbing like this (and I do it a lot) I always try to remember this quote: Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it." --Brian Kernighan

Comment: I always figured it would just be encouragement to become twice as smart before I have to start maintaining things.